# How to check if nonce has been used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, nonce

In my Rails 3.1.5 application, I am using the [ims-lti gem](https://github.com/instructure/ims-lti) to perform third-party authentication. To perform the authentication, three things must be done:

1. Check that the request signature is correct
2. Check if the timestamp is too old
3. Check that the nonce has not been used

The first two are done, but I am having trouble with the nonce check. Most questions I have found deal with generating nonces in Rails, not checking them.

There are several related questions that use the [oauth-plugin gem](https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin) to check the nonce:

[Rails oauth-plugin: multiple strategies causes duplicate nonce error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811559/rails-oauth-plugin-multiple-strategies-causes-duplicate-nonce-error)

[OAuth signature verification fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200240/oauth-signature-verification-fails)

```
return false unless OauthNonce.remember(nonce, timestamp)
```

Unfortunately, the oauth-plugin gem hasn't been updated since 2013, and is not compatible with the version of the oauth gem required by the ims-lti gem.

It does not appear that the [oauth gem](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby) supports validating nonces.

Is there a canned way to check the nonce, whether in native Rails or through a gem, or am I relegated to:

- Creating a nonce table
- Checking that the nonce is not already in the table
- Storing the nonce and timestamp in the table
- Cycling the table to drop entries with an expired timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I ended up doing.

Create a database table to store the nonce values:

**/db/migrate/<timestamp>_create_oauth_nonces.rb**

```
class CreateOauthNonces < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :oauth_nonces do |t|
      t.string :nonce
      t.timestamp :timestamp
    end
    add_index :oauth_nonces, :nonce
    add_index :oauth_nonces, :timestamp
  end
end
```

Since nonces are short-lived, they should be deleted after they are no longer needed. The Sidekiq and Redis gems can be used to perform nonce deletion asynchronously:

**/app/workers/oauth_nonces_worker.rb**

```
class OauthNoncesWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(nonce_id)
    OauthNonces.find(nonce_id).delete
  end
end
```

In the sessions controller, nonce handling is performed - check if the request has expired, then check the nonce value, and if it passes, enqueue the nonce deletion:

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
request_timestamp = DateTime.strptime(params[:oauth_timestamp], '%s')
nonce_expiry_time = 5.minutes

if request_timestamp < nonce_expiry_time.ago
    # Handle expired request here
end

nonce_exists = OauthNonces.find_by_nonce(params[:oauth_nonce])

if nonce_exists
  # Handle re-used nonce here
end

# Store the new nonce in the nonces table
nonce = OauthNonces.create!({ nonce: params[:oauth_nonce], timestamp: timestamp }, without_protection: true)

# Use Sidekiq and Redis to queue the nonce deletion
begin
  OauthNoncesWorker.perform_in(nonce_expiry_time, nonce.id)
rescue Redis::CannotConnectError
  # Okay to swallow error, since enqueuing the nonce deletion is for performance only
  # Users shouldn't be prevented from logging in just because the nonce deletion worker isn't running
end
```

This isn't the best solution, and has room to be improved.

- Since the nonces don't need to be persisted for more than a few minutes, using a database table is overkill. Better to cache them, and save a DB request per login.
- Instead of queuing every nonce deletion, instead a background worker can purge the expired nonces once a minute.